# Trying to Redirect from site1.com to site2.com using htaccess without changing url in the addressbar

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there anyway I can redirect from site1.com to site2.com without having url change in addressbar.

I have tried different solutions available here which are mostly for redirect rule/conditions within the same domain. There is no example available for redirects to a different domain.

Unfortunately I do not have access to httpd config due to shared hosting plan for which host wont do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either do this server side by proxying the traffic. 
By either a dedicated load balancer or by apache [mod-rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [mod-proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for example.

Here is an example with mod-proxy.

```
ProxyRequests Off
 <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyPass / http://site2.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://site2.com/
</IfModule mod_proxy.c>
```

However if you don't have access to httpd config and only .htaccess I doubt your provider will let you run any kind of proxying.

An alternative is to use a simple html based hack with frames or iframe.

```
<frameset rows="100%">
 <frame src="http://site2.com">
</frameset>
```

Comment: One comment - you probably want ProxyPassReverse to be http://site1.com instead, otherwise the location bar will show the second site instead of the first one.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought ProxyPassReverse was mostly to ensure references to site2 was replaced with site1 in the document returned to the client?

Comment: On checking, we're both wrong. You should keep site2 in ProxyPassReverse, but it doesn't change the contents of the document, it only changes any redirects sent, as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse